# Set observable and just update if changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Well, im consuming an API Service:

```
getServers():Observable<Server[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get(this.API_URL).pipe(map((servidores:Server[]) =>{
        const servidores2 = plainToClass(Server, servidores as object[]) ;
        servidores2.forEach(servidor => {
            this.getApps2(servidor.ServerId, apps =>{
              servidor.Applications = new Array(apps.length);
              servidor.Applications = apps ;
            });
        });
        return servidores2;
      }));
  }
```

So im calling it from a "ServerListComponent":

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() servers$: Observable<Server[]>;
  public serverCards:Server;
  constructor(private serverAPI: ServersService){}

  ngOnInit(){ this.servers$ = interval(5000).pipe(startWith(0)).pipe( switchMap(() => this.serverAPI.getServers())); }

  ngOnDestroy() { }

}
```

And of course, in HTML, im sending to another child component:

```
  <server-card *ngFor="let server of servers$ | async" [serverCards] = "server" ></server-card>
```

Now my problem, is that its blinking and re-doing the view every 5 sec, even if the data is the same. So what i want to do is just refresh the view only if there are changes.

```
export class ServerCardComponent{ 
  private _serverCards: Observable<Server>;
  asyncTabs: Observable<Tabs>; 


  @Input() 
  set serverCards(servidor:Observable<Server>) {
    if(servidor == this._serverCards){
      //if data is the same do nothing
    }else{
      //only update if data changed
      this._serverCards  = servidor;
    }


  }

  get serverCards():Observable<Server> {

    return this._serverCards;
  }
```

Of course that last dint worked, **i dont know how to "compare" both Observable and only updates the template if is not the same data**, i read for there that i have to use maybe distinctuntilchange or zip, but i dont know how to implement for my solution.

My template for the cardServer is below in case u needed:

```
<mat-card class="dashboard-card"> 

    <mat-card-header class="header-cardsita">

        <div mat-card-avatar class="led-box"><div class="{{serverCards.State | stateLed}}"></div></div>
        <mat-card-title>
            <div mat-card-avatar class="redondo-avatar-pc"></div>

          <p ><a class="title-cardsita" href="/Admin/server/{{serverCards.ServerId}}">{{serverCards.Hostname}}</a> </p>
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle><p class="subtitulo">{{serverCards.Ip }}</p></mat-card-subtitle>

        <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
                <a class="enlace" href="/Admin/server/{{serverCards.ServerId}}">
                    <button mat-menu-item>Details</button>
                </a>

                <button mat-menu-item>Edit</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Delete</button>
              </mat-menu>


    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-divider class="divisor-top"></mat-divider>


    <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
        <p class="content-icons"><i class="material-icons color-accent">group</i>{{serverCards.Team}}</p>

        <p class="content-icons"><i class="material-icons color-accent">subdirectory_arrow_right</i>{{serverCards.OperatingSystem}}</p>



        <p class="content-icons"><i class="material-icons color-accent">label</i></p><p class="description">{{serverCards.Description | truncate : 90 : "..."}}</p>

        <mat-divider ></mat-divider>

              <br>
              <ul *ngIf="serverCards.Applications" >
                  <li *ngFor="let app of serverCards.Applications">{{app.Name}}</li>
              </ul>







    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at `distinctUntilChanged`

Comment: ya sure, but i cant make it work with distinctUntilChanged, can you help me with that?, always i get errors at trying implementing :(

Comment: The last example described here https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged should give you an idea on how to make it work

Comment: I been trying with that: in my services i implemented like this: `getServersDistinct():Observable<Server[]>{
    return interval(5000).pipe(startWith(0)).pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get(this.API_URL), map((servidores:Server[]) => plainToClass(Server, servidores as object[])))); 
  }` but is not working at calling it like this     this.servers$ =this.serverAPI.getServersDistinct();
Help me please :(

Comment: `distinctUntilChanged` requires a function that does the comparison for your case to work. I have prepared this simulation https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mjgzoc?devtoolsheight=60 which I hope can help. You need to revisit the comparison logic, which in my example is very simple, but I hope it gives you an idea

Comment: Thanks for your example, i fixed before reading that, but i was still no understanding, but with your example now i get it. Thank you so much @Picci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is my final solucion, hope it can help someone with my same problem:

First i create a observable that is consuming my API every 5 seconds

```
servidores$ =  interval(5000).pipe(startWith(0)).pipe( switchMap(() => this.getServersOnly()));
```

¿What is next? of couse, i just want to receive only the distinct ones.

```
getServersDistinct():Observable<Server[]>{
   return this.servidores$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((p:Server[], q:Server[]) => (JSON.stringify(p) === JSON.stringify(q))));
  }
```

**Profit**, now i have observables in my template with the pipe | async now updates only when the data has changed. I dont know if the code can get better but works for me.